# WSDL Error in PHP: No address associated with <port>

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to soap web services and I am trying to create a web service that fetches student information from the database. However, my wsdl file produces the following error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
      <faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: No address associated with <port></faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**soap_service.wsdl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<definitions name="Student"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap"
             targetNamespace="http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/Student"
             xmlns:tns="http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/Student"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <message name="studentFetchRequest">
        <part name="admission_number" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <message name="studentFetchResponse">
        <part name="student" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="StudentPortType">
        <operation name="getStudent">
            <input message="tns:studentFetchRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:studentFetchResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="StudentBinding" type="tns:StudentPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="getStudent">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/Student/getStudent"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="StudentService">
        <documentation>WSDL File for Fetching a Student by Admission Number</documentation>
        <port binding="tns:StudentBinding" name="StudentPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/soap_service.wsdl"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**SoapServer.php**

```
<?php
$server = new SOAPServer('http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/soap_service.wsdl', ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]);
print_r($server->getFunctions());
```

**SoapClient.php**

```
<?php
try {
    $server = new SoapClient("http://localhost/Html/Soap/soap/soap_service.wsdl", ['trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]);
    var_dump($server);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
}
```

Any help in understanding the cause of the error would be appreciated :)